# Solid language/framework for this app

Tags: web-applications, database-connection, application-design

I am wanting to build a web based file archiving tracking app and would like some feedback on how would be the best way to build it.

I am trying to build web based file archiving app (like Apple Time Machine) that watches an external hard drive and when ever a file/folder is added it writes the file path to a database that can be searched later. So if user added this folder "My Folder" on this date "04/16/12" to external HD "Drive 1" and needed to find that folder or its contents at a later date they could search the name, date or drive name and the corresponding results would be returned.

The user would have to select the Hard Drive that needs to be watched and the app would take over from there.

• Can I do this from strictly a web app or do I need an local app/plugin that can communicate with my web app?

I am just looking for some direction as to where to start, my background is pretty much HTML,CSS, PHP but I am not opposed to learning something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what I am thinking after reading your question is what you meant:

-You need to identify the user's storage device each time he/she logs in.
-If you want to constantly monitor what is being added or deleted, you need to have that access from the user. However, you also need to think what if user goes offline? How will you track change while he is offline.

I don't think you can strictly do it from web-app unless you assume the user is connected to internet all the time. You need some kind of local app to monitor their storage device when they are offline and automatically update your database as soon as they are online.

For what you have to do: PHP is fine for implementing what you need when the user is online. For local app in user's machine, you can code a file tracker (when they are offline) and send it to the server via JSON or other after they are connected online. For creating local program, I would recommend you to take a look at python since it is very clear and easy to learn language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. This is a big help!